# Getting max values from SQL Server join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I've struggled with a SQL Server query for a while and realize that I have to get help from someone who knows SQL Server (much) better than I do.

Environment: SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT      
    t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, 
    t2.OUR_ORDER,
    t3.CUST_INVOICE
FROM t1 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 
        ON t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO = t2.ORDER_REM5 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN t3
        ON t2.ORDER_REM5  = t3.INV_REM5

GROUP BY t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t2.OUR_ORDER, t3.CUST_INVOICE
ORDER BY t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO,t3.CUST_INVOICE
```

This is the result I get with the query above:

```
SUPPL_ORDERNO                  OUR_ORDER CUST_INVOICE
------------------------------ --------- ------------
143914                         64228     179890
143914                         64228     179935
143914                         64228     179995
143914                         64228     179999
143914                         64228     180067
143914                         64228     180148
326042                                   
326052                         64549     180219
326086                         64633
```

I get multiple `CUST_INVOICE` for each `SUPPL_ORDERNO` and `OUR_ORDER` combinations but I only want to return the latest `CUST_INVOICE` (=largest invoice number).

This is the result I want to return:

```
SUPPL_ORDERNO                  OUR_ORDER CUST_INVOICE
------------------------------ --------- ------------
143914                         64228     180148
326042                                   
326052                         64549     180219
326086                         64633
```

Summary:

1. if there are more than one (1) `CUST_INVOICE` for the combination of `SUPPL_ORDERNO` and `OUR_ORDER` I want to show only the `CUST_INVOICE` with the largest number
2. if there is no `OUR_ORDER` and no `CUST_INVOICE` I want to it to be shown as empty
3. if there is an `OUR_ORDER` and no `CUST_INVOICE` I want to it to be shown as empty

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Remove t3.CUST_INVOICE from GROUP BY and use MAX(t3.CUST_INVOICE) function into SELECT statement

```
SELECT t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t2.OUR_ORDER, MAX(t3.CUST_INVOICE) AS CUST_INVOICE
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO = t2.ORDER_REM5 
        LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.ORDER_REM5  = t3.INV_REM5
GROUP BY t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t2.OUR_ORDER
ORDER BY t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t3.CUST_INVOICE
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e26ae/1)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is using `row_number()`.  This adds a sequence number to things, in this case by invoice number within each order:

```
select suppl_orderno, our_order, cust_invoice
from (SELECT t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t2.OUR_ORDER, t3.CUST_INVOICE,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO, t2.OUR_ORDER order by t3.cust_invoice desc) as seqnum
      FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
           t2 
           ON t1.SUPPL_ORDERNO = t2.ORDER_REM5 LEFT OUTER JOIN
           t3
           ON t2.ORDER_REM5  = t3.INV_REM5
     ) t
where seqnum - 1
ORDER BY SUPPL_ORDERNO,CUST_INVOICE
```

By ordering the invoices in a descending order, the most recent gets a value of "1", which is used for the filter.